# Grep with a regex character range that includes the NULL character

Tags: bash, grep, hex, bsd, null-character

When I include the NULL character (\x00) in a regex character range in BSD grep, the result is unexpected: no characters match. Why is this happening?

Here is an example:

```
$ echo 'ABCabc<>/ă' | grep -o [$'\x00'-$'\x7f']
```

Here I expect all characters up until the last one to match, however the result is no output (no matches).

Alternatively, when I start the character range from \x01, it works as expected:

```
$ echo 'ABCabc<>/ă' | grep -o [$'\x01'-$'\x7f']
A
B
C
a
b
c
<
>
/
```

Also, here are my grep and BASH versions:

```
$ grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting that [`$'...'` is a shell quoting construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html), this,

```
$ echo 'ABCabc<>/ă' | grep -o [$'\x00'-$'\x7f']
```

would try to pass a literal NUL character as part of the command line argument to `grep`. That's impossible to do in any Unix-like system, as the command line arguments are passed to the process as NUL-terminated strings. So in effect, `grep` sees just the arguments `-o` and `[`.

You would need to create some pattern that matches the NUL byte without including it literally. But I don't think `grep` supports the `\000` or `\x00` escapes itself. Perl does, though, so this prints the input line with the NUL:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\0\n' |perl -ne 'print if /\000/'
bar
```

---

As an aside, at least GNU grep doesn't seem to like that kind of a range expression, so if you were to use that, you'd to do something different. In the `C` locale, `[[:cntrl:][:print:]]'` might perhaps work to match the characters from `\x01` to `\x7f`, but I didn't check comprehensively.
The [manual for grep has some descriptions of the classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions).

---

Note also that `[$'\x00'-$'\x7f']` has an unquoted pair of `[` and `]` and so is a shell glob. This isn't related to the NUL byte, but if you had files that match the glob (any one-letter names, if the glob works on your system -- it doesn't on my Linux), or had `failglob` or `nullglob` set, it would probably give results you didn't want. Instead, quote the brackets too: `$'[\x00-\x7f]'`.

Comment: Are `grep ['a'-'b']` and `grep '[a-b]'` the same too?

Comment: @oguzismail, other than the first being a glob, aren't they?

Comment: That the first is a glob is not a negligible difference. They aren't the same.

Comment: @oguzismail, for the purposes of this issue, it is a negligible difference.

Comment: Misleading anyway. `['a'-'b']` may expand to empty string (`nullglob`), `a`, `b`, both `a` and `b`, or `[a-b]`, or may fail the command (`failglob`), while `'[a-b]'` will always be `[a-b]`.

Comment: @oguzismail, yes, actually you're right in that the glob there in the question would match any one-letter name, assuming it works at all. I tend to, on purpose, ignore `failglob`, `nullglob` and the chance of matching strange filenames so as to keep to the point, but one-letter filenames are a more likely problem. Call it lazyness if you will, but the disclaimer about all the quirks of the shell language is sadly rather long to include in every post...

Answer (score 3):

On BSD `grep`, you may be able to use this:

```sh
LC_ALL=C grep -o '[[:print:][:cntrl:]]' <<< 'ABCabc<>/ă'

A
B
C
a
b
c
<
>
/
```

Or you can just install `gnu grep` using `home brew` package and run:

```
grep -oP '[[:ascii:]]' <<< 'ABCabc<>/ă'
```